# Android animate element from fragment to activity

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, fragment

I'd like to animate a view from a fragment to make it goes to a place inside the activity, how can I do that?

I can make the view moove inside the fragment place but not inside the activity.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it, the activity contains the fragment, right ?
So how would you move something inside the fragment but not inside the activity ?

Comment: In this activity I've some component that belongs only to her and I've a container where I've a fragment, and I'd like to make a view move from the fragment where it stands to a new place in the activity.

Comment: If the fragment is embedded inside the activity, your activity can access the view inside the fragment, so you can make your activity perform an animation on the view

Comment: yes but I want that the animation put the view outside my fragment to bring it inside the activity